# Не могу разобраться в синтаксисе SASS

Tags: css, sass

код SASS:

`.cmn-toggle-switch__htx span::before
     transition-property: top, transform`

на выходе код CSS:

```
.cmn-toggle-switch__htx span::before{
    -webkit-transition-property:top,-webkit-transform;
    transition-property:top,-webkit-transform;
    transition-property:top,transform;
    transition-property:top,transform,-webkit-transform;
}
```

Подключена библиотека bourbon.
На выходе, в css мне требуется только это:

```
transition-property:top,transform;
```

Comment: и никакого автопрефиксера не стоит? похоже на результат его работы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно, что в сборщике стоит `autoprefixer`. К примеру, если это `Gulp`, найдите задачу, в которой собирается `CSS`, и в ней увидите примерно такую строку `.pipe(autoprefixer('last 3 versions'))`. Закомментируйте ее или измените на количество поддерживаемых версий.

Хотя может быть, что у вас и другая переменная. Поэтому в идеале нужно найди к какой переменянной записывается `require('gulp-autoprefixer')`, а потом искать строку, где он выполняется.

Если не получится, дополните вопрос примером кода из сборщика.

Comment: да, все верно - это autoprefixer. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Proshka не за что, обращайтесь!